# What is Mobile Safari doing to the DOM after a video finishes playing?

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video, mobile-safari, dom-events

I have a page with a <video> and also a lot of Javascript. On the iPhone and iPad, when you click to play the video, it starts playing in that full-screen player (as usual for the iPhone/iPad). But when the user clicks the "Done" button, and that full screen window disappears and the user is brought back to the web page, many Javascript-y things on the page are broken.

Specifically, I'm using the flowplayer "playlist" plugin which takes a "template" and dynamically populates a list of html with it (similar to how "jquery-tmpl" jQuery templates work). After clicking "Done" on a video, the page shows up again with all of this dynamically populated html gone, and just the template with its placeholders showing.

So it's as if Safari is re-rendering the original page HTML but my `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` initialization code isn't getting re-run accordingly.

Does anyone have any insight into what exactly Mobile Safari does to a web page after it returns from showing a video? If I can understand what events are and aren't happening, I can tap into the right thing and re-initialize my page javascript.